# Convert .amr file to .mp3 in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mp3, amr

How do i convert `Base64` encoded string, which is basically .amr media file sent from android application, to .mp3 file in ruby.

Comment: which os have you use?